# What are actually the consequences of Object.clone() not calling super.clone()?

Tags: java, clone

I know the convention for implenting `Object#clone()` says you should call `super.clone()` to get the copied object.

But I am just wondering what the consequences are, if I don't. So let's assume this example:

```
class SomeClass implements Cloneable {
    private Object someField;

    public SomeClass(Object someField) {
        this.someField = Object someField;
    }

    public Object clone() {
        return new SomeClass(this.someField);
    }
}
```

I feel that this is not *right* (TM). If I want some copy constructor or copy method I would just use that and not `Object#clone()`.

However, while stumbling upon this in some legacy code, I just wondered: Is this actually dangerous? Or just *creative*, but actually bad style?

Comment: you simply shallow copy the object instead of deep copying it. an excess to someField will affect both objects

Comment: super.clone() also only creates a shallow copy by default, so this is not a concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this actually dangerous? Or just creative, but actually bad style?

The danger is that the `SomeClass` could be sub-classed.  This means the sub-class will also have to override this method or it won't actually return am instance of the same type.

Another potential problem is that an optional field is added to `SomeClass` but you forget to update the `clone()` method.

If you use `super.clone()` you wouldn't have to worry about these issues.

Comment: I wonder, how calling super.clone() prevents second issue you have  mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so the concern would be: Actually you decide against using the Java clone API, but you *make it look like you are doing it*.

And that eventually will make your forget to update this method. With a copy-constructor or custom copy method you probably would have thought about that.

+1 for the subclass argument, because that is really breaking the clone contract.

Comment: @xxlali `super.clone()` copies all the fields, not just the one which existed at some point when you wrote the method. Add a field, and you don't have to remember to change the code else where.

Comment: I would add to the above response that if you add mutable fields, it's required that you make deep copies of them after you call the super.clone() method.

Comment: @Slimu They might be required depending on what you expect clone() to do.  In general this API is best avoided IMHO.